# Need to access the simple list in Thymleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, web-services, thymeleaf

controller:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    model.addAttribute("result", al.add(inputLine));
```

HTML:

```
<ul th:each="al: ${result}">
    <li th:text="${al}"></li>
```

Need all the added value in html. But it returns true. Is there any way to get all the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the result of the `ArrayList#add(..)` method as model attribute, this method does not return the array list itself, but a boolean.

You should add the arraylist itself:

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(inputLine);
  al.add(inputLine);
}

model.addAttribute("result", al);
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Please use the checkmark to mark the question as answered so others know a solution has been found.